# Laravel - Yajra DataTable build with Infyom package does not show data

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, yajra-datatable, infyom

I already use Laravel 8 with Yajra DataTable et wanted to test Infyom Laravel-Generator that seems to be a great package.

I created my first test app and generated a Yajra DataTable.
I see the datatable page, **I was able to create a first record, the table in the database is updated, but the page shows always no record** even if I refresh it.

And **there is no Search input on the page**.

I see **nothing in the Laravel logs**.
When I open my browser (firefox) in dev mode, I see **no XHR request** that seems to be abnormal since I see such a request on a website with datatable build without Infyom package.

Having a look in the source of the html page, no datable script is present!

So the pb should come from the genaration script, I used this cde :

```
php artisan infyom:scaffold Es5 --fromTable --tableName=es5 --datatables=true
```

I'll appreciate any help to debug/explai this.

Thanks in advance.

PS : Let me know if you want me to share some code, but now I don't know which part should be useful.

Comment: "_there is no Search input on the page_" - Show us your DataTable definition, as well as the HTML where your `<table>` is defined. Does the ID used in your table tag match the ID used by the DataTables code? `<table id="my_example" ... >` and `$('#my_example').DataTable( { ... } );` (I am not familiar with Infyom).

Comment: No pb with the table def, but I still search for the html def - where infyom put this paramater?

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand that comment.

Comment: I don't know in which file html is defined

Comment: OK - I think we are talking about completely different things - my mistake - please ignore my comments. I saw the `datatable` tag and assumed it was [this](https://datatables.net/) - but I think that is incorrect.

Comment: It's Laravel Yajra DataTable I'll check if there is a better tag. Found and updated.

Comment: OK - so yes you are using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/), after all.

Comment: Under the hook I thing it's the same ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to publish datatable add_on html & buttons

and found the solution here

https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/laravel-generator/issues/84

Answer (score 0):

this could happen if the number of columns you defined inside your HTML table is not equal to the number of fields you are trying to fill inside your javascript code.

Comment: I defined nothing (not done by Infyom?), Do you knpw in what file(s) Infyom defines this parameters?

Comment: is there any javascript errors inside the firefox console?

Comment: No, I see only the GET requests.

Answer (score 0):

How did you implement it?

Did you use service implementation? I suggest to handle it in this way

Comment: I follow standard Infyom doc (existing app and creation from a table). It seems that is service implementation.

Comment: I need your code, There should be something wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the adminlte-generator scaffold, there is an issue with the javascript is not being imported. Here is the solution:
https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/adminlte-generator/issues/87

Find `@yield('third_party_scripts')` in views/layouts/app and change it to `@stack('third_party_scripts')`.

Answer (score 0):

I had put my 2 days on that but the answer was so simple. make sure the yajra/datatable JS script is loading while you trying to render table

## Simply change in your layout/app.blade.php

from

```
@yield('third_party_scripts')
```

to

```
  @stack('third_party_scripts')
```

Comment: Seems like a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69216764/9018946)